# What happened to Stack Overflow Android app?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, android-app

I had Stack Overflow app on my phone. When I got my new phone, Stack Overflow Android app wasn't transferred because it wasn't in Play Store. When I search "StackOverflow Android app" on Google, it returns [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.stackoverflow) URL but it looks like it was unpublished from Play Store. I was able to find v1.0.4 APK in [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/stack-exchange/stack-overflow/stack-overflow-1-0-4-release/stack-overflow-1-0-4-android-apk-download/).

[iOS version](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808) is still there.

What happened to the Android app?

Comment: Could it have been removed from Play Store due to recent privacy policies introduced in Play Store, and devs forgot to fix it?

Comment: Cross-site dupe on MSO: [What happened to the Stack Overflow app for Android?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373307/559745) No official answer yet.

Comment: @Floern thanks, I couldn't find that question.